# Why are American and British TV-series often so different in style?

Tags: production

I've noticed that American TV-series often use a lot more of dramatic narration and music, repetition of dialog and scenes, and a fast paced and energetic editing, while British TV-series have a tendency to be more subtle, calm and focused on continuous and more natural dialog.

For example: [Dragons Den](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8Lin2S5o5M) vs. [Shark Tank](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATb4nPguMww) or Ramsey's Kitchen Nightmares [UK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTHdx2eR8vs) vs [US](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FayGQYszBJY).

Where did this cultural difference come from? How can we form a context of relevant factors to understand the different preferences?

I'm sure that this example could be done using different countries, but let's use US and UK as a good case of comparison.

Comment: I think it depends on what you're talking about too, because even with American television there's a big difference to the procedural aspects of regular network tv (or even a genre show vs soapy melodrama) vs the nuances and streamlined story telling of middle of the road cable or premium cable/streaming. I do agree though that most British TV series go with an earthy sense of realism and tend to have lower budgets with the exception of some "period" dramas...

Comment: This is an interesting question, but feels like the thesis of a sociologists paper on TV narration. I vote this question unanswerable as it delves far too deep into individual directorial styles, spans decades of filming development across boarders, budgetary differences and a viewership so diverse it's impossible to compare without becoming entirely opinion based.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zyv4jGWEzxY

Comment: I'd say that despite the fact that American and British people speak the same language, they are different cultures, separated by thousands of km, so their expectations of what they would like to see in a TV show is bound to be different (even if there is a lot of crossover). The question is, why do you think they should be the same?

Comment: The average person has a short attention span and maybe the American producers have decided that they need these viewers to get high ratings and justify their existence. Maybe the UK producers aren't obsessed with ratings and can target a more intelligent audience. I personally tend to like low-key shows such as Antiques Roadshow, American Pickers, and BBC documentaries.

Comment: @colmde I wouldn't expect them to be the same, but when you see an interesting difference it's nice to understand what's behind it.